# Stop text from breaking next line

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I am using *React*, *styled-components*, and *media queries* at the moment. I have 3 media queries at; **480px**, **768px**, **1200px** - my text when scaling between these on a desktop does not hold the same structure.

I have an **idea** to use two styled components one for the first line of the title and one for the second and then make sure that each one has `white-space: nowrap;`. But, I am not sure that this is the best solution... **Any suggestions?**

Here is a visual example of what I am working with:

[image]

Here is the line breaking:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "non-breaking-space" HTML entity `&nbsp;` instead of the regular spaces at the positions that should not break / should form a unit or line

```css
h1 {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>The fastest way&nbsp;to&nbsp;finance NFTs</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good, however you can use two span elements within the h1 and give them a display:block; and white-space: nowrap;

```js
<h1>
  <span className="block whitespace-nowrap">The fastest way</span>
  <span className="block whitespace-nowrap">to finance NFTs</span>
</h1>
```